# How to handle all Exception in Custom Exception Class?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, fortify

I want to handle all exceptions to a Custom Exception Class. I don't want to raise Custom Exception in try block I want to every exception will catch by my custom Exception Class.

**I don't want to do this:**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception");
        throw new CustomException("Hello World");
    }
    catch (CustomException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**I want this:**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception");
        throw new Exception("Hello World");
    }
    catch (CustomException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public CustomException()
    {
    }

    public CustomException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public CustomException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

    protected CustomException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
        : base(info, context)
    {
    }
}
```

Hope you get my question.

Comment: Whats wrong with that code?

Comment: You want your `CustomException` class to be a `super class` from which all existing exceptions are inherited, right? Well I'm not sure you can do that, but you'll certainly won't achieve this goal by inheriting your `CustomException` from the `Exception` class. It should be the other way around...

Comment: I don't get your question, because you didn't ask one :)

Comment: When i throw Exception like `throw new Exception("Hello World")` it cannot handle automatically. I need to raise CustomException which is not possible for me in my current application so i want that Every Exception will catch in CustomException class

Comment: And why don´t you simply catch every Exception instead of CustomException? You could create a new Object within the catch-block - lets call it UserException, which contains the actual exception and handles it...

Comment: @LarsKristensen I want to use CustomException Class instead of Exception Class in all Exceptions without any typecast

Comment: You can't. That's pretty much the end of the story.

Comment: *I want to use CustomException Class instead of Exception Class in all Exceptions without any typecast*, but WHY?  You haven't explained why you need this.  As far as I can tell this is a VERY bad design.

Comment: @Ravi, I understand your problem, but that's still not a question - that's a demand.

Comment: I see no good reason does not catch classic Exception. But in fact you cant do this...

Comment: Catch all exceptions and then in the `catch` block send them to your `CustomException` class. There you can maybe encapsulate them.

Comment: You can't do that because C# doesn't let you shoot yourself in the foot. What if the raised exception is an Out Of Memory exception and you treat it like a CustomException? Apples are not Oranges, it's as simple as that!

Comment: Actually we are using HP Fortify tool to find and resolve the code vulnerabilities. So in every catch HP Fortify want to use a Custom and Individual Exception rather than just Exception class.

Comment: @Ravi, You should really have mentioned this in your question, so that people who use Fortify could give some insight. I haven't used Fortify, but I'm guessing that they don't want you to "Catch any exception and treat it as a CustomException". Without researching it, I'm guessing they actually want you to throw CustomExceptions instead of just using the Exception class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the existing Exception classes.

But you can catch the exception and convert it to a CustomException:

```
try
{
    try
    {
        // Do you thing.
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new CustomException("I catched this: " + e.Message, e);
    }
}
catch(CustomException e)
{
    // Do your exception handling here.
}
```

I don't know it this is what you want, but I think this is the closest you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to achieve this, beacause you want to treat every exception as if it was a CustomException. Well, why not just treat every exception in that way? Handle every exception the way you would handle your CustomException. If there are some Exceptions that you don't want to handle as a CustomException, then what you want to achieve is not what is in you question.

If you *absolutely **must*** treat everything as a CustomException, you could do something like this;

```
try
{
   //Something that causes any form of exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw new CustomException(ex.Message); //Caught and handled in another place.
}
```

However, I don't think that's a sensible approach.

Comment: Even if this did some additional good, it's usually best practice to pass `ex` into the constructor to set [CustomException.InnerException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx).

Comment: @ErikPhilips I agree, but the constructor for the OPs CustomException takes a string (or a string AND the inner exception). But if this is actually the behaviour that the OP wants, then I assume the inner exception isn't important. Also, I think there are much worse consequences to using this approach :)